# Reverse JS select menu order and add custom option at the end

Tags: javascript

I`m a bit new to JS so I apologize in advance if I ask any stupid questions.

I found this script in StackOverflow and made a few small tweaks. Script comes from user "user2935177" with the help of Calvin.
My issue is that I want to reverse the order of the years (to, new to old) and add a custom option at the bottom ("Before 1950").
I have found many questions/answers about using custom orders in JS but am to novice to implement it in the code.

Anyone willing to assist and if possible explain how I can then add a custom option at the end of the list ?

```
<script>
var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
    min = 1930
    select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.text = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
</script>
```

Many, many thanks in advance !

Comment: I would recommend that you research "javascript for loops" and learn exactly what they do. I think you could solve this yourself if you understood them

Comment: Why would you want a "before 1950" option when your min date is 1930? Shouldn't it be "before 1930"?

Comment: 1950 was indeed a typo, should have been 1930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to start at max, and go to min by stepping backwards instead:

```
for (var i = max; i >= min; i--) {

}
```

And then just add this after your loop:

```
var customOpt = document.createElement('option');
customOpt.value = -1; // Or whatever value you'd like it to have
customOpt.text = "Before 1950";
select.appendChild(customOpt);
```

Comment: Thank you Jake, I tried something similar (in the loop) before but I never got the combination of changes right.

Comment: Sorry for second comment (hit enter). The second part I don`t get right yet (I did read the loop instructions mentioned by JensB), I either get the custom option at the top or under every line in the list :-( , any clue where this goes wrong ?

Comment: Figured it out :-) . I missed a parenthesis. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your loop line so that it starts from the max value and works towards the min value

Change this line:

```
for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
```

to this:

```
for (var i = max; i>=min; i--){
```

This last line basically means start at max value and then continue to loop until i is less than min, and i-- means subtract one as oppose to i++ which means add one.

I would recommend you to read more about for loops as you will use them alot: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Thank you JensB, you guys respond extremely fast; very much appreciated !